# Banshee doesn't respond to the multimedia keys after upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, banshee, multimedia

Rhythmbox does respond to the keys, but it is the only one. VLC does not respond too (while it did on 15.10).

The multimedia keys are supported in the plugins.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same trouble, you could try  following the instructions here:
https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1275

Comment: Although this is a workaround that works, I don't like that this way I de-assign the multimedia keys from their default behavior, as this way I can't control other media players. I guess the main problem is somewhere else in the connection between Ubuntu and Banshee... But where?